Webtoon where the fl dies after killing her brother, the emperor, and is returned to the past
The fl has straight black hair, she is a princess i believe and has been tormented by her family her entire life. At some point they realise her crush on the ml, they got her engaged and made the ml's (silver hair i think) life very hard (killed his sister maybe??), in the first life their relationship was not good. By the end of her first life she kills her awful brother (blonde) who is now emperor. By killing him it activates some sort of curse that kills her i think. In her first life she dies in the throne room in the ml's arms in regret. Then she wakes up as a child, regrets making the ml's life hard and tries to aim for the throne and not get involved with the ml.

Sorry found it through someone else's question! It's Carnephelia’s Curse is Never Ending
